# How to install ubuntu to use 2 disk as a combined lvm on root

Tags: lvm

I have bought a machine that have 2 4TB disk. I saw some information saying that I can create a ubuntu machine with 7TB disk in '/' based on lvm.

However, I made a lot of attempts but all failed trying to make this happen.

I tried normal install of ubuntu but the '/' can only be based on 1 disk which is only 3TB.

I tried created lvm first and install on this lvm. But got error starting ubuntu... Basically installation failed. I am very desperate.. can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product details, so we don't know which installer you're asking about.  For some releases there are also choices in installer, so providing Ubuntu product (Server? Desktop? Core? *flavor*?) and also release is also useful (*in allowing us to better help you*)

Comment: It is ubuntu desktop latest version 22.04.06

Comment: You'll need to clarify as your details are inconsistent; the *latest* version of Ubuntu Desktop is the 2023-October release; ie. Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop, with the older LTS release from 2022-April (22.04) currently only at 22.04.3 (not .6) with 22.04.4 updated ISO expected out early next, but no releases beyond 22.04.5 even scheduled; so do you mean 20.04.6 (which has a .6; which is the 2020-April release; or something older).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It typically is not recommended to span LVM across multiple drives. If either drive fails, you lose all data on both drives. You do then have an 8TB backup drive?